# Javascript always return null when I try to get content from asp.reportviewer

Tags: javascript, reportviewer

I want to print reportviewer content directly without save as pdf, excel or word. After searching from Google, there is a solution like code below:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function printdiv(printpage) {
        var headstr = "<html><head><title></title></head><body>";
        var footstr = "</body></html>";
        var newstr = document.getElementById(printpage).innerHTML;
        var oldstr = document.getElementById("body1").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("body1").innerHTML = headstr + newstr + footstr;
        window.print();
        document.getElementById("body1").innerHTML = oldstr;
        return false;
    }

<div id="body1">
    <input name="b_print" type="button" class="ipt" onclick="printdiv('div_print');" value="Print" />
<div id="div_print">
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Width="944px" ShowPrintButton="true" SizeToReportContent="True" AsyncRendering="false" ></rsweb:ReportViewer>
</div>
```

The problem is, it come out error said 'Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null'.
What had I missing ?

Comment: There is no tag with an `id` of `"printpage"`

Comment: @FarhadKhan `printpage` is a variable, not a string.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. As far as I can tell, this code produces no error. I copied it in a [codepen](https://codepen.io/jeremythille/pen/GRqVvNQ) Although I added a missing `</div>`, not sure if this is the problem; I guess it is.

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript code should go last in the `body` tag. What is happening here is that your javascript is running first but it can't find the element with id `body1` since that markup is not in defined yet. You can also define it in the head in a `script` tag with an `src` attribute.
It should be like this:

```
<head>
  <script src="my_script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="body1"></div>
  ...
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function printdiv(printpage) {...}
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I downvoted, because the function is called after a click on a HTML button : `onclick="printdiv('div_print');"` The JS does _not_ run before HTML is loaded.

Comment: I believe the initial question is missing a closing script tag in the example provided. Technically this answer works although the script tag does not need to be moved.

Comment: I had try to move the script to the end of body, it still no help.

Comment: that was a </script> for the javascript function. I miss to put it here.